# SymPy: Getting special solutions in two different vectors

Tags: python, sympy, linear-algebra

I want to use SymPy solve for special solutions to Ax = 0:
[image]

Using this code:

```
from sympy import solve

Vec = sp.Matrix(np.matrix([[1,5,7,9],
                 [0,4,1,7],
                 [2,-2,11,-3]]))

print(sp.linsolve( (Vec, sp.Matrix([[0],[0],[0],[0]])) ))
```

I get the correct output: `{(-23*tau0/4 - tau1/4, -tau0/4 - 7*tau1/4, tau0, tau1)}`

However, I'd like the two special solutions (corresponding to multiples of tau0 and tau1) in two different vectors, like:

[image]

Is there a way to get these two separate special solution vectors for each tau, rather than having them all in one?

Comment: Is there an issue evaluating the result at the two different tau values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better approach is to use `Vec.nullspace()` rather than `linsolve`:

```
Vec = sp.Matrix([[1,5,7,9],
                 [0,4,1,7],
                 [2,-2,11,-3]])
print(Vec.nullspace())
```

Outputs:

[Matrix([
[-23/4],
[ -1/4],
[    1],
[    0]]), Matrix([
[-1/4],
[-7/4],
[   0],
[   1]])]

Comment: Thanks, Ben! This draws out the importance of the nullspace concept.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer you'll be looking for, but looking at the [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve), `sp.linsolve` returns "A FiniteSet containing an ordered tuple of values".

There is no inherent sympy way to get special solutions separately.

One alternative is for you to use regex to separate them out, see example code (you can format it to your exact liking):

```
import regex as re
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
Vec = sp.Matrix(np.matrix([[1,5,7,9],
                 [0,4,1,7],
                 [2,-2,11,-3]]))

ans_ = sp.linsolve( (Vec, sp.Matrix([[0],[0],[0],[0]])) )

# there might be a better regex to do this

# replace tau0
sol1 = [re.sub(r"(\S*(tau0)\S*.)", "", str(temp)) for temp in list(ans_.args)[0]]
sol1 = [0 if x=='tau0' else x for x in sol1] 

# replace tau1
sol2 = [re.sub(r"((-+).\S*(tau1)\S*)", "", str(temp)) for temp in list(ans_.args)[0]]
sol2 = [0 if x=='tau1' else x for x in sol2]
sol1, sol2
```

Output:

```
(['- tau1/4', '- 7*tau1/4', 0, 'tau1'], ['-23*tau0/4 ', '-tau0/4 ', 'tau0', 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```py
>>> from sympy import Tuple
>>> sol = {(-23*tau0/4 - tau1/4, -tau0/4 - 7*tau1/4, tau0, tau1)}[0]
>>> v = list(ordered(Tuple(*sol).free_symbols))
>>> Matrix(sol).jacobian(v)
Matrix([
[-23/4, -1/4],
[ -1/4, -7/4],
[    1,    0],
[    0,    1]])
>>> s0,s1=_[:,0], _[:,1]  # all rows of 0-th and 1-th column
>>> s0
Matrix([
[-23/4],
[ -1/4],
[    1],
[    0]])
>>> s1
Matrix([
[-1/4],
[-7/4],
[   0],
[   1]])
```

Comment: Can you do this in a way where the solution is not hardcoded, and where it works with any number of free variables?

Comment: The answer was updated to do this in general. `v` will contain the variable for which a vector is given.

Comment: Look at the answer I just posted, Vec.nullspace() provides the special solutions directly